# CircleCI: Trigger test post-hook only on certain branches

Tags: geometry, circleci

I have a `circle.yml` file that looks something like this:

```
general:
  branches:
    only:
      - master
      - develop
      - /release-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/

test:
  pre:
    - docker-compose run $SERVICE npm install
  override:
    - docker-compose run $SERVICE npm test
  post:
    - docker-compose run SPECIFIC_COMMAND // this should only trigger for branches that fall under /release-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/
    - docker-compose stop
```

Unit tests run when merging to `master`, `develop`, or `/release-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/`.

However, there's a certain command in the post-hook under tests that I would *only* like to trigger when merging into `/release-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/`. This command must run before the final one, `docker-compose stop`, which is why I haven't used a [deployment](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration/#deployment) block.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this isn't quite possible in the `test` block (unlike the `branches` or `deployment` blocks).

The best way around this was to place the conditional logic in a shell script that accessed the `$CIRCLE_BRANCH` [environment variable](https://circleci.com/docs/environment-variables/). The shell script in turn would be triggered all the time.